# Aligning 6+ divs with 3 divs per line

Tags: css, html, positioning

So i have to align some divs in a wrapper div. This is the Code:

```
<div id="tiles-wrapper">
    <div class="tile">asdfasdf</div>
    <div class="tile">asdfas</div>
    <div class="tile">asdf</div>
    <div class="tile">asdfasdf</div>
    <div class="tile">asdfas</div>
    <div class="tile">asdf</div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS Code:

```
/* TILES */
#tiles-wrapper{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 960px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tile{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

I need to have 3 divs in one line. The first and last div in each line have to be placed at the border of the wrapper div without any padding or margin. The second div in each line should be centered with some margin on the left and right side.

The problem is that I must not have rows in my html content. I need to have all the divs lined up after each other.

The divs should be positioned like this:

```
|[1]------[2]-------[3]|
|[4]------[5]-------[6]|
|[7]------[8]-------[9]|
...
```

Is there a good CSS or JS method to do this?

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/STS5F/5

Comment: css will do this no need for js, does the divs need the specified width? what version of IE do you need to support?

Comment: Ok. It would be great if css would do this. IE7+ would be great but IE8+ would also be ok.

Comment: Make the widths of the tiles add up to the width of the wrapper if you want the right one aligned to the right... Apart from that, it's already working.

Comment: The problem is that I have to have some margin in between.

Comment: Are you saying that you need the wrapper to be re-sizable, so that the 3 items in each row dynamically resize to use all available space, or is the wrapper statically sized?

Comment: BTW: I find that dabblet is much easier to work with for layout questions: http://dabblet.com/gist/5255371

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use :nth-child(n) Selector

```
.tile:nth-child(3n+1) {
    /* position of the first column */
}

.tile:nth-child(3n+2) {
    /* position of the second column */
}

.tile:nth-child(3n+0) {
    /* position of the third column */
}
```

Comment: This here is what I was thinking too. An example could be something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/AxCmN/1/

Comment: Oh wow. Tanks for the answer. I hadn't thought of using it that way. :D But due to the fact that IE8 wouldn't support this I just used it with jQuery. :) heres the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/STS5F/12/

Answer (score 1):

I once came up with this weird thing

```
.justify-content { text-align : justify; position : relative; }

.justify-content>* { display : inline-block; }

.justify-content:after { content : ''; display : inline-block; width : 100%; height : 0; display : inline-block; }
```

Just add the `justify-content` class to your element and it's content will be justified.
But You'll have to remove the floats.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/STS5F/11/

Comment: I have to say that this would work to, although it's not the best method i can think of. :) thanks for the answer.

Comment: @jurihandl I know it's not the best, it's very flexible though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want your columns spaced out, you can simply give your `.tile` dividers a `margin-left` of 30px, then give each `nth-child(3n+1)` a `margin-left` of 0.

```
.tile{
    ...
    margin-left:30px;
}
.tile:nth-child(3n+1) {
    margin-left:0;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/STS5F/10/).